# CSS a:link keep original color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Is it possible to tell a link not to change color in CSS and use the default one.

Example

I have a text in red and that text is a link too. Normaly that text will change blue because it's a link, but I want it to stay red.

So is there a global style for a:link to select no color at all ?

Comment: uh... anchor tags are always links... so you would just set `a { color:red; }` in your css

Comment: @Joseph: No, anchor tags can also be used as a link target: `<a name="example"></a>`. (Of course, nowadays one would simply use an `id` attribute on another available element, but some care for old browsers which don't understand these.)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try this in your stylesheet:

```
a:link {
   color:inherit;
}
```

Note that you then probably should make sure you have some other way to identify links, or your users will be confused. (I.e. don't remove the underlining, too.)

If you want to deal with browsers not supporting `inherit`, I suppose repeating the definition which originally set your color will do.

As an example, assume the class `important` should be shown in red:

```
.important {
    color:red;
}

.important a:link {
    color:red;
}
```

But of course it is not nice to have to double all color indications. I assume one could do something in JavaScript (looping through all the `a` elements and giving them the right class explicitly).  (I have no IE available to test this.)

Comment: Thanks but Andrew have a point. IE7 doesn't give a damn about that. Any hack for this?

Comment: For IE7 you could always just style the `a` tag with `inherit` for `color`, and then add another line with `*color:;` and fill that value with whatever color the `p` tag is.

Comment: If this answer doesn't work for you in IE9, don't forget to add a doctype to your document: <!doctype html>

Answer (score 1):

If all of your `a` tags are contained within a paragraph tag you can just set the `color` of the `a` tag to `inherit`. You could also just set a style for all `a` tags to have whatever colour the paragraph tag has. A quick warning about `inherit`, there are older versions of IE which don't support it(IE7 and earlier).