# Variable formatting in Link_to

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am looking to pull a hex value from a field into the link_to line for rails. I have found how to format a standard link in line with the following

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Show', security, {:style=>'color:#FF6A00;', :class => 'css_class'} %></td>
```

I am looking to make the color a change value based on the specific record. I know that this goes in the face of typical css formatting. I don't want to do the color evaluation in the css file as there will be many, many colors that will be used. I can make standard text change color with the following code

```
<td style="color:#<%= security.subcategory.color %>"><%= security.subcategory.color %></td>
```

For some reason, this approach does not work within the link_to line. I'm sure that I am missing so sort of formatting with the code. I'm sure that I am missing something with formatting a link inline.

Thanks for the help

Comment: A little confused ... in one block of code, you're styling the link but, in the other, you're styling the actual `<td>` element. Can you clarify your intent a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: Good observation. Truly I'm trying to stylize the text within the TD tag as opposed to the entire element. I could resort to applying the color to the entire cell, but what I’d really want is just the link_to text. When I inspect the element in chrome, It reads    <a color="#113F8C" href="/securities/AAPL">AAPL</a>

Comment: Thanks! Just added an answer ... hopefully a helpful one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not trying to change the color of the link dynamically after the DOM has loaded, your code is quite close and you should be able to 'combine' your two code snippets above as:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', security, { style:"color:##{security.subcategory.color};", class: 'css_class'} %></td>
# note that the double pound sign (##) is intentional. 
# The first is for your actual CSS declaration 
# The second is part of Ruby's string interpolation so that security.subcategory.color is rendered in the style option
```

This code snippet should color the link and not the table cell.

Comment: In this case, should I include the # in value of the color hexcode field or not? In other words, should there be the ## that you suggest in addition to the "#FF6A00" stored as a variable?

Comment: My bad! If your DB field has the `#` in it, you would not need the double #s. Sorry about that. I should have made that clear in my response. You only need the double #s if your DB does _not_ have the full hex value (i.e., #FF0000).

Comment: Craig, you are a scholar and a gentleman! I owe you an adult beverage. That did it!

Answer (score 1):

The color of the TD is not inherited to the link by default.

Check: [CSS a:link keep original color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850023/css-alink-keep-original-color)

Comment: Thanks, this does work to get everything in the TD tag to pick up the new color, but is there a way to get it to apply the color only to the contents of what is in the link_to span?