# css styling links - getting messed up with a href's

Tags: html, css

With help I've got this list to be laid out and coloured they way I want.

https://jsfiddle.net/2t3cqr5m/

However I'm adding A HREF's to the lists and now the list values are changing style and colour, reading that from my main css script.

```
<li class='menu'><a href='#'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Learn HTML </a></li>
<li class='menu'><a href='#'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Create my own web site: 
  <ol>
    <li class='menu'><a href='#'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Development Articles </a></li>
    <li class='menu'><a href='#'><span class="icon-indent"></span> News and Stuff </a></li>
    <li class='menu'><a href='#'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Funny Cat Pictures </a></li>
  </ol>
</a></li>
```

How do I ensure they don't change and use the style shown in the example ?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking not to change color when it was hovered?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: So the code in the question doesn't have the CSS that is at the other end of the link … and the HTML is *different*.

Comment: And it looks like [this is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204634/how-to-disable-automatic-links-coloring-without-selecting-a-color) anyway.

Comment: sorry for the poor question.  The layout is correct. The issue is when I add the `A HREF` the formatting changes and uses css from another page.  I'd like to keep the formatting as it appears now and have the `link`, `visited` styles the same `LI` formatting currently and have the hover work as it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following CSS:-

```
.menu a:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
         color: #000000;
}

.menu a:hover {
        color: #2693ff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mac3Lgv6/

Comment: Love it when you get a down vote without an explanation.

Comment: yes, and to be 'on the safe side', for the question and all the answers...

Comment: Have you checked out the jsfiddle? What is different in your version to the jsfiddle?

Comment: @Rocket Given the code example you have given the following edits work perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/mac3Lgv6/  Maybe you have some code else where causing the CSS to not render correctly.

Comment: Thanks that has helped. My other page was causing the issue.