# Text turns purple after click

Tags: html

I find that the text turns purple with an underline after the link is clicked.
Even when I refresh it a few times, it still remains purple with an underline.
How can I keep the text from changing?

```
            <a
              href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2RNcPRtAiY"
              target="_blank"
            >
              <p class="video-title">
                Talking Tech and AI with Google CEO Sundar Pichai!
              </p>
            </a>
            <p class="video-author">Marques Brownlee</p>
            <p class="video-stats">3.4M views &#183; 6 months ago</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: Already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204634/how-to-disable-automatic-links-coloring-without-selecting-a-color. Your change is due to browser defaults or `user agent stylesheet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to remove the default styles for the "a" tag itself.
[This will solve your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919682/remove-all-styling-formatting-from-hyperlinks)

Answer (score 1):

That is the standard way that browsers indicate that a link is a [visited link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) (e.g. the URL it points to appears in the user's browser history).

Apply CSS to change it. You will probably want to use the `:visited` pseudo-class.

MDN has an [introduction to CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS) if you need it.